# Should my kid get a flu shot if I'm coming down with something?

Tags: vaccination, pediatrics, influenza, toddler

I've been putting off getting flu shots for myself and my toddler because I've been busy, and finding time has been difficult.

Now I'm coming down with the flu. (Or a cold or something - you know how hard it is to tell them apart!)

There's plenty of advice on whether to get a flu shot if you're sick (like [this article](http://coldflu.about.com/od/fluvaccinequestions/fl/What-Will-Happen-If-I-Get-a-Flu-Shot-While-Im-Sick.htm), and [this other article](http://www.onemedical.com/blog/live-well/flu-shot-sick/)), but I can't find any on whether my toddler should get a flu shot while I'm sick.

Will the flu shot that toddlers get lower their body's ability to fight off a real infection at the same time? That is, is my daughter more likely to catch what I've got if she gets a flu shot now, or will it make no difference, or will it end up helping her body?

Really I'm trying answer, should I take her to get a shot today, or wait until she and I are both healthy?

Comment: Welcome to Healt.SE! Its's doubtful you'll get an answer "today" (which taking timezones into account might already be past), so I recommend you talk to your doctor. However, this is an interesting general question!

Comment: @YviDe Indeed, it does have value to future readers. My daughter actually got a stomach bug at the same time I got a cold, so I didn't take her to get a flu shot.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is not recommended to get a flu shot while fighting any infection or illness as it could add stress to the immune system (I've had this assumption confirmed by my doctor). If your child was infected by the bug you have (some of the infectious agent made it into his/her body, but his/her immune system is keeping it at bay for the time being), the bug could be on its way to causing illness. If this is the case, the child's body is already working to deal with the pathogen and extra stress from the flu shot may overwhelm his/her system.

In short, my recommendation from my experience and knowledge would be to wait until you are sure you are both healthy and infection free.

Comment: Please note the comments on the answer by Soapkz. Those same comments apply to your answer.

Comment: Here on Health, we [*strongly encourage*](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/1) using references. They are the only way in which we can tell if information is reliable or not. If you are struggling to find good sources, check out, [What are reliable sources?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/112) If you want to learn more about our site's stance on answers without references, check out, [Should answers without references be immediately deleted?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/283) Thanks :)